# How to stop Firefox console log from cutting off beginning of log output?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I have a complicated script with a lot of debugging output. When I check it, Firefox's console log always starts in the middle of script execution, making it impossible for me to see what is going wrong at the beginning of the script. It seems to have a maximum limit to what my script can output, making development a major pain in the tuchus.

I have tried this in both regular Firefox and the Developer edition. I have set all the about:config devtools.hud.loglimit  and devtools.performance.memory.max-log-length to 1000000000, the maximum allowable value. Is there a way to turn this truncation off?

I've also tried having the script append log entries to a comment in the `<head>` of the page instead of writing to console.log, but as I'm trying to log objects so I can look at them, JSON.stringify(object) is choking on cyclical reference errors, and even if it worked that would not be an idea solution since it's much easier to browse objects in the console.

Comment: Gee, thanks for the helpful downvote without commenting as to how the question could be improved or giving any sort of clue what's wrong with it.

I was specifically sent here to ask this by a link on the main Firefox site. I wouldn't have chosen to ask it here, I thought they would have developer forums over there. If you have some sort of problem with me asking it here, the least you could do is explain how you think it could be improved.